# can someone provide a good resource for understanding 2 opt heuristic?

Tags: heuristics, traveling-salesman

I have looked into `wikipedia` and [this MIT slide](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-053-optimization-methods-in-management-science-spring-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_053S13_lec17.pdf). A step by step iteration of the algorithm with a clear example would be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-opt

Comment: yes seen this already

Comment: There is no answer to be accepted -_-

Comment: oh thanks for pointing it out. i have accepted the previous answers now.